# Not found z library when compiling zabbix-server

Tags: linux, configure

I have a problem with compiling zabbix-server on CentOS 6.2.
Command line is:

```
./configure --enable-server --with-mysql --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl 
--with-jabber --with-ssh2 --with-openipmi --with-ldap --enable-static
```

But error occures:

```
checking for main in -lz... no
configure: error: Not found z library;
```

Full configure output is here:  http://pastebin.ru/WmDP7UL0

I already tried to do:

```
yum install zlib zlib-devel zlib-static zlibrary zlibrary-devel
```

But it was unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your attention.

UPD. Config log posted here: http://pastebin.ru/WNtQu9eR and shows this error:

```
configure:7366: checking for main in -lz
configure:7385: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -rdynamic  -static conftest.c -lz  -lm -lrt  -lresolv >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Post config.log instead.

Comment: Config log is here: http://pastebin.ru/WNtQu9eR

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
```

But it *is* found previously, which points to something else. Check your ulimits to make sure you don't have a low max open file count.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. `yum install glibc-static` was help me. But now I don't know what to do with this error: `checking for main in -lssl... no configure: error: Not found ssl library`. I have installed openssl and openssl-devel. It doesn't help.